# Solving polynomial systems with homotopy. Where is the bottleneck?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, polynomials

I have a polynomial system with $n+k$ unknowns ($n+k$ can be greater than 8), that is known to have a limited number of isolated solutions.

I want to solve this system numerically, but if I plug it in an algebraic computing system (Macaulay2 or Bertini) and try to solve it with homotopy continuation, the PC just remains blocked, and I can't find any solution.

I am trying to understand why this happens, with the following consideration:
ALL the solutions are in some way equivalent (I mean that if $(x_1,..x_n)$, than the other solutions are just permutations of this array), so I am interested in computing just 1 solution, not all the possible solutions.

Here is my question

1. Where is the bottleneck of the homotopy method, in the number of solutions or in the number of variables?
2. The fact that I am interested only in one solution, may speed up the method just analyzing a single homotopy path?
3. Is there a way in Macaulay2 to calculate only a single solution, and not all of them?

To give more details about the system, if I have $k+n$ unknowns ($k<n$), then I have $(n+1) + {n \choose 2} +{n \choose 3}$ equations and $k!$ equivalent solutions. The degree of the system is always 4, and I have one equation of degree 1, $n$ of degree 2, ${n \choose 2}$ of degree 3 and ${n \choose 3}$ of degree 4. The system can be solved easily with Groebner basis when $k=2$ and $k = 3$, but also computing Groebner basis for higher values of $k$ becomes very slow..

Thanks!

Comment: In case it helps people not native or not fluent enough in English (including myself): **bottleneck** = *a ​problem that ​delays ​progress*; from here: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/bottleneck

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to provide more information on the system, e.g. "How many equations?", "What is the degree of the equations?" or even a link to an example system, which one could try to solve.

Comment: for the benefit of a homotopy theorist, what is this "homotopy" method? Does it perchance involve integrating something on a sphere (or a simplex boundary)?

Comment: @JesseC.McKeown It's a really neat method: try *homotopy continuation method* in your favorite search engine!

Comment: OK, so the idea is you start with a function whose zeroes are easy to find, and perturb it in such a way that correcting the old zeroes is not-too-difficult... so, have you checked whether those assumptions are indeed correct? that it's possible to choose not-too-many perturbations, AND those perturbations have solutions near enough eachother AND the correct-the-solution step actually happens quickly? because it sounds like you've got a very complicated system of equations already, and even the First Step might be difficult.

Comment: I am trying with a very standard starting system: if $F$ is my original system, then I use $G = F-F(xo)$ where $x0$ is a random value, so I know a zero of G. What I see is that, even for very small values of $t$, $F*t + (1-t)*G$ is high even in $x0$, because of the 4th degree equations. 

Another element that probably blocks everything is that tipically the system is non squared, so I can not use most of the solvers (eg Newton Rhapson) to get the zeros of the perturbed system $F*t + (1-t)*G$ starting from a zero of $G$. I should look for solvers of non squared systems in that case.

Comment: Won't intermediate systems typically have no solutions, because there are more equations than variables?