# Why is solving polynomial systems NP hard?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, computational-complexity

Solving polynomial systems is known to be a NP hard problem; however it is not completely clear to me where this complexity comes from.

My interest is in the case of systems of  multivariate polynomials over the real field.

Intuitively, I can imagine that part of the problem consists in the counting of the roots of the system: Bezout bound states that the number of roots is bounded by the product of the degrees of the polynomials composing the system; so if we have $n$ polynomials of degree 2, we will have at most $2^n $ solutions,  so, if $t$ is the time needed to compute a solution, we should perform at most

$$
t2^n
$$

operations. My question is:

1. What can be said about t , the complexity of calculating a single solution?
2. Is still a NP hard problem to solve non linear polynomial  systems that are known to have only one solution?
3. Is there any literature about this topic, studying the complexity of solving polynomial systems?

thanks!

Comment: The context is not quite clear. Are you taking about multivariate case? Over reals, integers, finite fields?

Comment: Yes, multivariate polynomials over the real field

Comment: You can encode 3-sat. The idea is equations $x^2-x=0$ make x Boolean valued and now encode intersection by product and complement by $1-x$.

Comment: There is an old MO question on this stuff.

Comment: This question is somewhat answered in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/115608/sat-and-arithmetic-geometry/115625

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Encoding 3-sat we prove that is NP hard to understand the solvability of a system, ie if a system has solutions. But if we know by construction that a system has solution (and also that is unique), things change?  what can be said about finding that precise solution (also numerically..)?

Comment: Then you have to formalize the algorithmic problem. Do you want the Turing machine to produce the right answer when the system has a unique solution and it can give garbage otherwise?

Comment: I would expect things to not change too much; the problem of UNAMBIGUOUS_SAT (SAT where there's guaranteed at most one satisfying assignment) is still known to have complexity implications (namely NP=RP) if it's in P, and it shouldn't be hard to craft polynomial systems from there.

Comment: Are you looking for a _theoretical_ answer here or a practical one, and what's the 'real problem' you're trying to solve?  What are your constructed systems?

Comment: @ Steven Stadnick Actually, I am trying to solve a big system, described at high level here  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234254/solving-polynomial-systems-with-homotopy-where-is-the-bottleneck
What I am experiencing is that most of the solvers spend a lot of time in counting the roots, while the time spent in calculating the various individual roots is much smaller. From this, I am trying to understand if it makes sense to modify the existing methods to make them calculate only one root, or if this is a lost battle (ie the problem is NP hard).

Comment: @ Benjamin Steinberg
The algorithm, theorethically, should take a system that is known to have roots and produce approximations of one of the roots.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106733/complexity-of-finding-solutions-for-a-system-of-polynomial-equations